# Quick Second Derivatives with Parametric Equations Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"A curve is defined by the parametric equations $x(t)=e^{-3t}$ and $y(t)=e^{3t}$. What is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in terms of $t$?"

So I guess I'm a bit confused about what the answer might look like here. I understand that to find the second derivative here, I have to divide the first derivative of the derivative of the first equation by the derivative of the $x$ equation here, but I'm confused about where that would put me for an answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the second derivative of a parametric equation follow this logic:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$ since both $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$ and then,
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\cdot \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Using the parametric equations above you should find that
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3e^{3t}}{-3e^{-3t}}$$

and thus
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2} &= \frac{d}{dt}(-e^{6t})\frac{1}{-3 e^{-3t}} \\
&= 2e^{9t}
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, so looks like using that logic I'm coming up with an answer that looks like the following: $\frac{e^{9x}}{3}$, is that looking right to you?

Comment: @joe Please see edit

Answer (score 2):

Call

$$x = e^{-3t} = z$$
$$y = e^{3t} = \frac{1}{z}$$

Thence

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = \frac{\text{d}(1/z)}{\text{d}z} = -\frac{1}{z^2}$$

Deriving again we get the result

$$\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2} = \frac{\text{d}(-1/z^2)}{\text{d}z} = \frac{2}{z^3}$$

Substituting back and you get

$$\frac{2}{(e^{-3t})^3} = 2 e^{9t}$$

Whence

$$\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2} = 2e^{9t}$$